# BigQuery regex remove/replace a list of text from a string

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

How would I go about removing a list of text within a string?
Essentially have a URL column and want to avoid grossly long regexp's and multiple nested replace functions.

Is there a way to declare a list of text such as "http", "www.", etc and have them removed from the column in one go?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use below simple approach

```
with t as (
  select 'Is there a way to declare a list of text such as "http", "www.", etc and have them removed from the column in one go?' col
)
select regexp_replace(col, r'http|www.|etc', '') cleaned_col
from t
```

with output

[image]