# REGEX certain rows of Data and keep the rest

Tags: regex, google-bigquery, text-extraction

I'm trying to extract the following data and convert it to a final column in BigQuery.

**Raw Data**
SAY LOWERS = BAD.Q
Virginia
SAY LOWERS = BAD.U
Oregon
Georgia
SAY LOWERS = BAD.U
SAY LOWERS = BAD.A
California

**Final Version**
BAD.Q
Virginia
BAD.U
Oregon
Georgia
BAD.U
BAD.A
California

Basically, I'm trying to remove "SAY LOWERS = " from all the data that has it, and keep everything after it, and keep everything that doesn't have that phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66594188/6456163) covers how to run `regexp_replace` in Google BigQuery, here is the query adapted for your use case:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(your_column_name, r'SAY LOWERS = ', '') final_column_name
FROM your_table_name
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a regex to remove a constant string from another one. Just use [`REPLACE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#replace):

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(your_column, 'SAY LOWERS = ', '') AS final_column
FROM your_table
```